# Execute SQL statement asynchronously

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asynchronous, locking

I want to execute a SQL statement asynchronously. The statement is something like

```
BEGIN TRAN  
    SELECT 1 
    FROM MyTable WITH (TABLOCKX)

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20' 

    ROLLBACK TRAN   
GO
```

which waits for a time duration. What I want to achieve is verify that table is inaccessible just after locking it for testing purpose.

I am using C# Entity Framework at code level and underlying database is SQL Server.

Comment: Why do that with an ORM?  You would be better of using `SqlCommand`

Answer (score 1):

You could use SSMS to run this query separate to your application.